# Why can't Mathematica integrate my function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

I am very new to Mathematica and have been trying to integrate a function p[f] that is expressed as follows

```
p[f_] := 2 ((b[f])\[Conjugate] a[f] + b[f] (a[f])\[Conjugate])/(s[f])
```

where

```
b[f_] = D[ A f^(-7/6)Exp[I (2 \[Pi] f t - \[Phi] - \[Pi]/4 + ((3 \[Eta])/(128 (Pi*f*M)^(5/3)))[1 + 20/9 (743/336 + (11 \[Eta])/
        4) ((Pi*f*M)^(2/3))*(\[Eta]^(-2/5))])], t]


a[f_] = D[ A f^(-7/6)Exp[I (2 \[Pi] f t - \[Phi] - \[Pi]/4 + ((3 \[Eta])/(128 (Pi*f*M)^(5/3)))[1 + 20/9 (743/336 + (11 \[Eta])/
        4) ((Pi*f*M)^(2/3))*(\[Eta]^(-2/5))])], A]


s[f_] := so(1/(f/215)^4.14` - 5/(f/215)^2 + ( 111 (1 - (f/215)^2 + (f/215)^4/2))/(1 + (f/215)^2/2))
```

but when I use the Integrate command, I get

[image]

I have tried adding assumptions and using NIntegrate as well, but nothing seems to work.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit:
After adding the numerical values for all my constants

```
 A = 2.3175*10^(-22)
 t = 0
 \[Eta] = 0.25
 M = 6.00304*10^(-6)
 \[Phi] = 0
 so = 10^(-49)
```

and using this new expression for p[f]

```
p[f_] = FullSimplify[2((b[f])\[Conjugate] b[f] + b[f] (b[f])\ 
[Conjugate])/(s[f]),Element[f, Reals]]
```

upon using

```
NIntegrate[p[f], {f, 20, 1570.42}]
```

I get

[image]

and if I use

```
Integrate[p[f], {f, 20, 1570.42}]
```

I get

[image]

Comment: You can only do a numerical integral if you assign numerical values to all the constants in your expression.

Comment: `Integrate[Conjugate[a+Sqrt[b*x]], {x, 0, 1}]` fails perhaps for a similar reason, which I would guess is because the form of the result depends on the parameters.  For example, try adding `Assumptions -> b > 0` or the opposite.

Comment: @mikado upon adding the numerical values to the constants, I get the error :  Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try \
increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral \
may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option

Comment: You can’t have a constant followed by square brackets as you do with `so[...]` in your definition of `sf`.

Comment: It would be good also for the answerability of your question to include the explicit integrate command that you use.

Comment: @CATrevillian I have removed the square brackets and have added the explicit commands as well.

Comment: There is a problem in the definition of `b`.  You write `D[..,t]` but earlier you said `t=0` . This results in `D[.., 0]`what is nonsense. You can only take a derivative relative to a variable that does not have a value.